# How to hide @Html.DropDownList if ViewBag is null or empty

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have @Html.DropDownList which take data from controller in edit mode. I need to hide DropDown element and show some message if list is null or empty.

I try with this code in view, but all the time give me result thet have, and show empty dropdown:

```
 @if(ViewBag.DatumRID != null)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.DropDownList("DatumRID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DatumRID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <h6 style="color:#ff0000"> NO RECORDS.</h6>
                }
```

And code from controller is here:

```
ViewBag.DatumRID = new SelectList(db.tbl_relacii.Where(x => x.DatumR == tbl_rezervacii.DatumP).OrderBy(x => x.DatumR), "relID", "DatumForDisplay", tbl_rezervacii.DatumRID);
```

when record fount dropdown is ok, but when record is null dropdown show empty.

Comment: Instead of ViewBag.DatumRID use the model:Model.DatumRID set the list on the model

Comment: The code in you controller is creating a `SelectList` - it cannot be `null`, just empty. - `var data = db.tbl_relacii.Where(....); if (data.Any()) { ViewBag.DatumRID = new SelectList(...); }`

Comment: Thank you @Stephen Muecke It`s work.

Answer (score 1):

Check list size also. For correct displaying data SelectList must contain more than zero items. Try this:

```
@if(ViewBag.DatumRID != null && ViewBag.DatumRID.Count > 0)
{
      <div class="col-md-10">
          @Html.DropDownList("DatumRID", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
          @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DatumRID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      </div>
}
else
{
      <h6 style="color:#ff0000"> NO RECORDS.</h6>
}
```

Update:
U may try update your controller code like this:

```
    List<SelectListItem> viewList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    viewList.AddRange(new SelectList(db.tbl_relacii.Where(x => x.DatumR == tbl_rezervacii.DatumP).OrderBy(x => x.DatumR), "relID", "DatumForDisplay", tbl_rezervacii.DatumRID));
    ViewBag.DatumRID = viewList;
```

And pass "viewList" object to DropDownList helper at razor markup.

Comment: I have this error **'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList' does not contain a definition for 'Count'**  At line: `@if (ViewBag.DatumRID != null && ViewBag.DatumRID.Count > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I searched around, and could find anything reasonable to work with.  Selectlists don't have a Count() or any() method like most lists.  Here's what I came up with:

```
@{
    var counter=0;
    foreach(var a in Viewbag.DatumRID)
    {
        counter++;
        break; //stop it so it doesn't iterate through the whole thing since that's unnecessary 
    }
 }
@if(counter>0){//put your dropdown here}
```